# Panda3d Robotics

Tags: c++, python, ruby, robotics, panda3d

The title makes it obvious, is this a good idea? I've been looking for a robotics simulator in languages i know (i know ruby best, then c++, then python -- want to strengthen here--, forget about javascript, but i know it).

i found something called pyro, but it probably doesn't fit my needs (listed below).

In my last university term i learned c++, then they took me to RobotC (which was only about 2 months of the term). Pyro seems similar but now i want something different.

I need something that allows to import graphics, allows 3d environments, allows to easily modify actions robot can perform. Also provides other things necessary for robot programming, like a sensor.

Comment: Have a look here - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533321/robotics-simulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533321/robotics-simulator

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go for ROS(gazebo) and write your nodes in C++ or python. You can follow Lentin Joseph's book on Learning Robotics Using Python. It helps you in building autonomous bots with ROS and OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Panda 3D is a good language to write your own robot system in.  It's written by CMU people, so it's very clean and makes a lot of sense.  It allows you to import very complex models from Maya or Blender.  It supports 3D environments.  Although it has its own scripting language for running actions (animations) imported from your modeling package, I prefer to write my own robot driver.  It supports three different physics engines, including its own basic version, Open Dynamics Engine (ODE), and most recently Bullet.  Although it supports collision detection, which allows triggering, it is an animation and graphic rendering system, not a robotics system per se, and so you'll have to craft your own sensor simulations beside or on top of it.  All in all, though, it is quite satisfactory.  Good luck.

Comment: Panda3D is not a language, and is not fully written by CMU people, it is actually mostly written by a few people solo contributors.

Comment: Panda3D is not a language in the same way that OpenGL is not a language, point.  It's implemented on top of either C++ or python.

Comment: Clarifying origins: "CMU has received a...award for its role in developing Panda3D...Panda3D is a game engine originally developed by the Disney VR Studio to create virtual reality rides, such as Aladdin’s Magic Carpet, at Disney theme parks. It eventually was used to build Disney’s online game, Toontown. It was released as open source software in 2002, but was not in a form that could be easily used by most game developers. Carnegie Mellon’s Entertainment Technology Center worked with Disney to create documentation, add features and generally make Panda3D more suitable for use by the public."