# Which technology should I use to develop this fisheye perspective game?

Tags: python, pyopengl, panda3d, quake

I'm going to develop a 3D game, that a player walks in a maze with a 3D first-person perspective, collects things and escapes a monster. The game itself is very simple, but as it is not for entertainment, but for a biological experiment, so it has some specific features:

1. We will project the graphics to a spherical screen with 3 projectors, so the graphics should be in a **fisheye trasformation**, and be **easily further transformable** (to deal with the merging between projectors).
2. There should be a functionality to **record data**, like the path of the player, and the time points when the monster appears etc. All the events should be recordable.
3. The game program could **interact with external devices** via USB. For example, whenever the player press a certain key, the program will tell an Arduino board to do something.

As my invesigation, I found three candidates of tool chain to develop such a game:

1. Develop **a MOD on Quake3 engine** + [Fisheye Quake](http://strlen.com/gfxengine/fisheyequake/). The problem I think would be that the Quake3 runs with a virtual machine, so that is it possible to implement the feature 2 and 3 above?
2. **Panda3D** + [FisheyeLens API](https://www.panda3d.org/apiref.php?page=FisheyeLens)
3. **PyOpenGL**. This is the most flexible way, but with the greatest workload I think.

I'm quite familiar with C/C++/Python, but this is my first time to develop a 3D game. My question is which tool chain is fittest for this project (or any other good options) ? What problem would I encounter?

Comment: It sounds like you've already identified suitable options and the rest is entirely subjective.

Comment: @Dolph No really. These options are just what I have investigated. I have no experience on them, and don't know if they would work for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's no answer yet, let me give my own thoughs here. I have no experience on 3D development and don't know if these technology would work. For some side reasons, I prefer Panda3D.

**Please note that I'm still open to accept other answers.**

---

**Why Panda3D?**

1. It is [well-documented](http://www.panda3d.org/documentation.php). This is always an import factor to choose technology.
2. It's in Python, which is a plus for me.
3. It's general-purposed (than Quake3). Panda3D can also be used [on robotics simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513998/panda3d-robotics) etc. which would be useful for me.

**Why not Quake3?**

1. It runs on virtual machine (QVM). I'm afraid that it's hard to record data or access external device.
2. At first I thought of Quake3 because it's at least a very classical code to read, but currently I realized that Quake3 can not do anything else except FPS-like game. If it worth reading, just read it, but not have to work with it.
3. It's not that flexible to transform the rendering of graphics. It's a game engine for purpose, not a general graphics processing library.

**Why not OpenGL?**

At this moment I think the Panda3D is bottom enough. If it's proved to be not as flexible as I need, I would turn to OpenGL then.